# Current time between date that we entered

Tags: c++

Okay, so, I'm making a program that will count between 2 dates. (First_date is already given, second we should make this of ourselves day/month/year) after that I want to make program count our second_date and tell if this date already was/is/or will be

```
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

    if (second_day < now->tm_mday + 1900)
        {
            if (second_month < now->tm_mon +1)
            {
                if (second_year < now->tm_year)
                {
                    cout << "We had: ";
                }
            }
        }

    else if (second_day = now->tm_mday + 1900)
        {
            if (second_month = now->tm_mon +1)
            {
                if (second_year = now->tm_year)
                {
                    cout << "Hey, you just entered our current date!" << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Right now we have: ";
                }
            }
        }

    else if (second_day > now->tm_mday + 1900)
        {
            if (second_month > now->tm_mon +1)
            {
                if (second_year > now->tm_year)
                {
                    cout << "We will have: ";
                }
            }
        }

    else
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Problem is that he simply skips this part. 
What is the best way to make it work?

Comment: Count what, the number of days between two dates? Or weeks? Skips what part? One thing to note is that you are using the assignment operator in the second "else if" rather than the equality operator. Is this intended?

Comment: Here are some low-level calendrical algorithms you could use: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html